# How to specify when joining to tables with the same primary key name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select request_id, request_created_date, request_complaint_type, request_descriptor, 
request_ferry_terminal
from nyc311_requests
    join nyc311_locations_ferries on request_id=request_id
where request_ferry_direction = 'Manhattan Bound' 
order by request_id
```

I have this code, and when I try to execute, it says that every time request_id is mentioned, it's an ambiguous column.

Comment: All you need is [SQL Alias](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm)

Answer (score 2):

you need to saw which table it's from, notice how I've added the table name to the request_id

```
select nyc311_requests.request_id, request_created_date, request_complaint_type, request_descriptor,
request_ferry_terminal
from nyc311_requests
    join nyc311_locations_ferries on nyc311_requests.request_id=nyc311_locations_ferries.request_id
where request_ferry_direction = 'Manhattan Bound' 
order by request_id
```

you can also give the tables aliases

```
select r.request_id, request_created_date, request_complaint_type, request_descriptor,
request_ferry_terminal
from nyc311_requests r
    join nyc311_locations_ferries lf on r.request_id=lf.request_id
where request_ferry_direction = 'Manhattan Bound' 
order by request_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your tables aliases.

```
select A.request_id, request_created_date, request_complaint_type, request_descriptor, 
request_ferry_terminal
from nyc311_requests A
    join nyc311_locations_ferries B on A.request_id = B.request_id
where request_ferry_direction = 'Manhattan Bound' 
order by request_id
```

You'll have to specify the alias for any field that appears in both tables but it's pretty simple once you know how to do it.